# Expect Rspec to raise exceptions in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec-rails

I am trying to test on a controller if it raises errors when mass-assignment protected attributes are to be updated.

```
expect do 
  post :create, account: {protected_attr: "blahblah"}
end.to raise_error
```

However Rspec says: expected Exception but nothing was raised

While if in spec file, we remove the expect block, like

```
post :create, account: {protected_attr: "blahblah"}
```

There will be an exception when running the spec:

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: protected_attr
```

How come does rspec's raise_error not capture the exception?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you're trying to get an exception on your `post :create, account: {protected_attr: "blahblah"}` but all this code does is return a http response.

You can't use `expect {}.to raise_exception` here.

To test the exception you shouldn't do it within the controller spec (I would do it on `spec/models/account_spec.rb`. Something like:

```
expect do
  described_class.create!(protected_attr: 'blahblah')
end.to raise_exception
```

On your controller you can just test for the response code to not be success:

```
post :create, account: {protected_attr: "blahblah"}

expect(response).to_not be_success
expect(response.status).to be(422) # you can be specific about the code you're expecting
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly answer for your question but it might solve your problem. You don't have test it in controller tests. Just test in in model specs. It is a concern of models in Rails 3.x. In Rails 4 will be used different approach.